# as3 how to ignore MOUSE_DOWN outside mask

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, masking, image-masking

I am working on a jigsaw-like game in as3 where irregularly shaped layers imported from photoshop are used to mask parts of their original background.

By setting cacheAsBitmap=true on the mask and its contents the result is a nice irregular shape with its transparent bounding portions left out.

However the invisible bounding areas are still detected at MOUSE_DOWN. I would prefer the mouse not be detected anywhere but on the visible masked part. At the moment I cannot detect the mouse on any other clips on the stage that might appear behind the overlapping transparent areas.

I have seen a solution here involving bitmap pixel detection which I have not found a way to apply as a solution. The contents of my masked areas are either shapes or MovieClips.

I hope someone can help me find a solution

Comment: Perhaps you should show some of your code. I got curious and did a simple test, and could not reproduce what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and the most stable approach to prevent the mouse events on the transparent area of bitmap graphics is to create a separate vector shape as the target for mouse and set the `mouseEnabled` flag to false to the bitmap or set `hitArea` property to this shape.

You can create such shape manually in the Flash IDE for the tests and even for the production. Sometimes it's more suitable to write the bitmap tracert script that creates contour shape in runtime by checking the pixel transparency.